# How to change elements in my list? My list splits on ',' while I want my list to split on ';'

Tags: python, list, split, element

**Right now I have the following list:**

```
row_2 = ['23-05-2020 14:28;World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG);Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games);Fortnite (Battle Royale games);FIFA (sport games);Red dead Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games);Man;18-25;7-12 uren per week;\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.',
' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.',
' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.;Uitdaging;Verbinden;Vrijheid;3;4;4;2;3;4;4;2;4;2;3;1;5;2;2;3;2;2;4;4;2;4;4;4;4;4;4;1;1;4;2;3;4;2;4;2;4;3;1;5;4;3;2;2;2;4;4;4;2']
```

**When I print the elements of the list, I get the following 3 elements as output:**

```
23-05-2020 14:28;World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG);Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games);Fortnite (Battle Royale games);FIFA (sport games);Red dead Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games);Man;18-25;7-12 uren per week;Vrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.

Uitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.

Verbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.;Uitdaging;Verbinden;Vrijheid;3;4;4;2;3;4;4;2;4;2;3;1;5;2;2;3;2;2;4;4;2;4;4;4;4;4;4;1;1;4;2;3;4;2;4;2;4;3;1;5;4;3;2;2;2;4;4;4;2
```

**However, I do not want to get these items as elements of the list, I do not want the elements to be split on ',' but on ';'. My output needs to look as the following:**

```
['23-05-2020 14:28', 'World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG)', Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games)', Fortnite (Battle Royale games)', ...] **And so on**
```

**How can I get the output I want to have?**

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[x for s in l for x in s.split(';')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string looks like the following, you can split on ';' as shown below:

```
myString = ('23-05-2020 14:28;World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online '
            '(MMORPG);Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games);'
            'Fortnite (Battle Royale games);FIFA (sport games);Red dead '
            'Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games);Man;18-25;7-12 uren '
            'per week;\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken.'
            ' Ik wil autonomie hebben., \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief '
            'en effectief voelen., \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met '
            'anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.;Uitdaging;'
            'Verbinden;Vrijheid;3;4;4;2;3;4;4;2;4;2;3;1;5;2;2;3;2;2;4;4;2;'
            '4;4;4;4;4;4;1;1;4;2;3;4;2;4;2;4;3;1;5;4;3;2;2;2;4;4;4;2')

myList = myString.split(';')
print(myList)
```

I get the following output:

```
['23-05-2020 14:28', 'World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG)', 'Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games)', 'Fortnite (Battle Royale games)', 'FIFA (sport games)', 'Red dead Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games)', 'Man', '18-25', '7-12 uren per week', '\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben., \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen., \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.', 'Uitdaging', 'Verbinden', 'Vrijheid', '3', '4', '4', '2', '3', '4', '4', '2', '4', '2', '3', '1', '5', '2', '2', '3', '2', '2', '4', '4', '2', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '1', '1', '4', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '4', '3', '1', '5', '4', '3', '2', '2', '2', '4', '4', '4', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your output you must use `split` method of strings such as below,

```
s="23-05-2020 14:28;World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG);Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games);Fortnite (Battle Royale games);FIFA (sport games);Red dead Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games);Man;18-25;7-12 uren per week;Vrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben."

l1=list(s.split(";")) #splits the string on ";"

print(l1)
```

output:

```
['23-05-2020 14:28', 'World of Warcraft/Guild Wars/EVE Online (MMORPG)', 'Counter Strike/Call of Duty: Modern Warfare (FPS games)', 'Fortnite (Battle Royale games)', 'FIFA (sport games)', 'Red dead Redemption 2/Spider-Man (Adventure games)', 'Man', '18-25', '7-12 uren per week', 'Vrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.']
```